# How to recreate transaction from thread dump

Tags: java, oracle, fatal-error

We have been having a problem where our JVM (HotSpot on Weblogic) terminates with a fatal error.

```
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xffffffff7a045f1c
```

We have analyzed and re-analyzed the fatal error logs ([Oracle: Fatal Error Log Troubleshooting](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/felog-138657.html)). The error log includes the thread running at the time of the error and its trace (first three lines below reading down the trace.) The trace is the same each time the fatal error occurs.

```
J  com.bea.wsrp.producer.container.ServletRequestImpl.setHeaders(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;Ljava/lang/String;)V
j  com.bea.wsrp.producer.container.RequestFactory.createServletRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Lcom/bea/wsrp/model/markup/IRuntimeContext;Lcom/bea/wsrp/model/markup/IMarkupParams;Lcom/bea/wsrp/producer/handlers/ServiceHandler$InvocationType;)Lcom/bea/wsrp/producer/container/ServletRequestImpl;+213
j  com.bea.wsrp.producer.container.RequestFactory.createServletRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Lcom/bea/wsrp/model/markup/IRuntimeContext;Lcom/bea/wsrp/model/markup/IMarkupParams;Lcom/bea/wsrp/model/markup/state/IOpaqueState;Lcom/bea/wsrp/model/markup/INavigationalContext;Lcom/bea/wsrp/producer/handlers/ServiceHandler$InvocationType;)Lcom/bea/wsrp/producer/container/ServletRequestImpl;+5
```

My question is, given a stack trace and our source code, how can we figure out the action needed (or section of code to test more thoroughly) to recreate this issue when the last part of our code that ran is ~80 lines down the trace and pretty generic (meaning lots of different actions run through it)? Are there any static code analysis methods that could help? Could searching the bytecode help? Or are we stuck without access to the vendor source?

Trial and error testing (including our standard performance/functional scripts) has failed to recreate the issue or even use the setHeaders method (top line of the above trace).

Thanks for any help on a new way to approach this issue.

Comment: is possible that issue was caused by the OS ? this message ""SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xffffffff7a045f1c" came from the weblogic var, or syslog?

Comment: @ThufirHawat: message is from the fatal error log so it is coming from the JVM. SIGSEGV is an invalid memory access.

Comment: I think is not your case here, but I had a segmentation fault one time ago, and the solution was to fix the date time of the server (because OS date differs from the file date). any way, hope you can solve this issue man. sounds tough

Answer (score 1):

If you mean recreate the same thread state, which you don't know what it was when it died, you could use `Thread.currentThread().setName(...)`

Some people use this to set thread state information in the thread name so that later stack dump analysis can give you some stateful information, for example a thread name could be something like:

`thread [abc] values [tx=1234, state=state1, user=someuser, starttime=123456]`

Comment: Interesting technique. I think it could help but a code change for this would be a tough sell. Was hoping to learn about something that I could do mostly offline.

Comment: Yes. Very Interesting technique

Comment: This guy wrote a bit about it http://blog.takipi.com/supercharged-jstack-how-to-debug-your-servers-at-100mph/